How to include year on year function calculation in Highcharter Tooltips?
Working in highcharts where the years will be selectable. I want to include a % change from the other year in the tooltips.
Test data:
test <- tribble(
  ~Year,    ~Type,    ~Total,    ~Median,
  1995,      'A',       20198,       1873,
  1995,      'B',        4589,        324,
  1995,      'C',       12984,       1209,
  1996,      'A',        3829,       2091,
  1996,      'B',        3829,       3045,
  1996,      'C',        3829,       9291,
  1997,      'A',       14023,       1829,
  1997,      'B',       16093,       2129,
  1997,      'C',        1893,        529
)

Calculate percent change between the two years:
percent_change <- function(year2_fig, year1_fig) {
  ((year1_fig - year2_fig) / year2_fig) * 100
}

How to refer to the the mouse selector position on the chart to feed in variables to this percent change function?
# --- create tooltip table ----
tooltip_category_text <- c("Median:  ",  "Percent change: " )
tooltip_formatted_values <- c(" {point.Median}",  "{point.percent_change()}")

my_tooltips <- tooltip_table(tooltip_category_text, tooltip_formatted_values)

Chart:
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column",
           marginLeft = 200) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(pointWidth = 18)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(labels = list(
    style =
      list(fontFamily = "Segoe UI",
           fontWeight = 100),
    enabled = TRUE
  )) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = test$Type,
           labels = list(
             style =
               list(
                 color = '#344a5e',
                 fontFamily = "Segoe UI",
                 fontWeight = 100,
                 fontSize = '12px'
               ),
             enabled = TRUE
           )) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    dataSorting = list(enabled = TRUE),
    data = test,
    type = 'bar',
    hcaes(x = Type, y = Total, group = Year),
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled = FALSE,
      style = list(
        color = '#344a5e',
        fontFamily = "Segoe UI",
        fontWeight = 200
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = my_tooltips,
             useHTML = TRUE)

I have seen the method to use a Javascript formatter but again I cannot reference a function within this.
hc_tooltip(
        formatter = JS("function(){return ('Type: ' + this.point.Type + '<br> Median : ' + this.point.Median + '<br> Percent Change: ' + this.point.percent_change(year2, year1))}")

This tooltip formatter is only working with the first point, why not the second, and what way can I include the third?

Wouldn't it be possible to calculate percent_change directly as a new column in test? If so, how is year2_fig defined if e.g. Year = 1995? You also have 1996 and 1997.

I need the data in a different shape for plotting the clustered bar chart which shows each variable for 2 selected years. I decided to calculate and present the results outside the chart after the years are selected
